# Updating a DLL on an already running IIS site

Tags: c#, iis, dll

We have a DLL that needs to be updated on a site to provide some endpoint changes. Just updating the DLL in the bin folder causes a server error due to the DLL being a different version than the assembly manifest.

I don't currently have a Visual Studio license, is there a way to update either the assembly manifest or the DLL's version number without recompiling the whole site?

Have tried updating the DLL, this caused an error because of the version number. Checked the Registry for any mention of the DLL or the version number, but to no avail. Tried manually editing the DLL as there was a version number in it, but this then causes an error about there not being an assembly manifest.

Comment: You're going to need to re build/compile and re-deploy the project for it to work correctly. If you don't have a license is the viable for you to just get the community edition of visual studio?

Comment: If the file you want to update is in your application's bin directory, you can copy the new file into that directory, and make sure that the one you are using has write permissions to that folder.